# Matrix NxN rotation 90 degrees - is it possible to do it better than O(n^2)?

Tags: c#, matrix

I need to rotate the matrix by 90 degrees clockwise - but the aim is to do it better than `O(n^2)`. I've found a lot of examples using 2 for cycles, one in another, but that is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Does 'rotate' mean, you just want a new matrix, that has the values of the old matrix, but their places rotated around? Or do you want to do some sort of mathematical rotation (which would be better suited for the math forum of stackexchange i think). Just checking before thinking of answer.

Comment: some feedback, wether your question was answered (i.e. by accepting an answer) would be nice.

Comment: Yes, it means, that I want a new matrix, that has value of the old matrix, but rotated around ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you can freely control the representation of your Matrix, i can give you one in O(1) :).

Let's say your matrix is in an object that fulfills the interface IMatrix

```
interface IMatrix
{
    double getValue(int index_x, int index_y);
    void setValue(int index_x, int index_y, double value);
}
```

You can implement that in different ways, for instance:

```
class RowBasedMatrix implements IMatrix
{
    //an array of rows
    double[][] values;
    //size of the Matrix
    int N;
    //this is explained later
    bool invert_x, invert_y;

    RowBasedMatrix(double[][] values, int N, bool invert_x, bool invert_y)
    { 
        this.values = values;
        this.N = N;
        this.invert_x = invert_x;
        this.invert_y = invert_y;
    }

    double getValue(int index_x, int index_y)
    {
        if(invert_x)
            index_x = N - 1 - index_x
        if(invert_y)
            index_y = N - 1 - index_y
        return values[index_y][index_x];
    }

    double setValue(int index_x, int index_y, double value)
    {
        if(invert_x)
            index_x = N - 1 - index_x
        if(invert_y)
            index_y = N - 1 - index_y
        values[index_y][index_x] = value;
    }
}

class ColumnBasedMatrix implements IMatrix
{
    //an array of columns
    double[][] values;
    //size of the Matrix
    int N;
    //this is explained later
    bool invert_x, invert_y;

    RowBasedMatrix(double[][] values, int N, bool invert_x, bool invert_y)
    { 
        this.values = values;
        this.N = N;
        this.invert_x = invert_x;
        this.invert_y = invert_y;
    }


    double getValue(int index_x, int index_y)
    {
        if(invert_x)
            index_x = N - 1 - index_x
        if(invert_y)
            index_y = N - 1 - index_y
        return values[index_x][index_y];
    }

    double setValue(int index_x, int index_y, double value)
    {
        if(invert_x)
            index_x = N - 1 - index_x
        if(invert_y)
            index_y = N - 1 - index_y
        values[index_x][index_y] = value;
    }
}
```

The idea is: you can reuse the `values` array from a `RowBasedMatrix` into the `values` of a `ColumnBasedMatrix` that is now effectively a Matrix with a value base mirrored at the diagonal from (1,1) to (N,N).

If you invert the x- or y-indices you can create a rotated Matrix. (Again inverting does not copy stuff around, but modifies the `getValue` and `setValue` Functions to access other fields).

If you transform a row-Based matrix into a column-based one, and then invert the x-coordinate, you effectively have a 90° clockwise rotated Matrix.

EDIT: expanded Example code

EDIT 2: an example code using the Matrix classes.

```
double[][] raw matrix_data = 
    new double[][] { {0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4} 
                     {1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4} 
                     {2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4}
                     {3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4} 
                     {4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4} };

int main(...)
{
    //this Matrix returns the values as visible above
    IMatrix default = new RowBasedMatrix(matrix_data, 5, false, false)

    double test = default.getValue(0, 4);
    //test is set to 4.0
    test = default.getValue(3, 1);
    //test is set to 1.3

    //this Matrix return values as if it had this value set:
    //  /0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0\ 
    // | 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0 | 
    // | 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.1, 2.0 |
    // | 3.4, 3.3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.0 | 
    //  \4.4, 4.3, 4.2, 4.1, 4.0/
    IMatrix xInverted = new RowBasedMatrix(matrix_data, 5, true, false);

    test = xInverted.getValue(0, 4);
    //test is set to 4.4
    test = xInverted.getValue(3, 1);
    //test is set to 1.1

    //now, if we use the column-matrix (switch x- and y-coordinates):
    //  /0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0\
    // | 0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1 | 
    // | 0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2 |
    // | 0.3, 1.3, 2.3, 3.3, 4.3 |
    //  \0.4, 1.4, 2.4, 3.4, 4.4/
    IMatrix columns = new ColumnBasedMatrix(matrix_data, 5, false, false);

    test = columns.getValue(0, 4);
    //test is set to 0.4
    test = columns.getValue(3, 1);
    //test is set to 3.1

    //if we invert this matrix's x-coordinates again, we get a 90° clockwise rotated value set
    IMatrix rotated = new ColumnBasedMatrix(matrix_data, 5, true, false);
}
```

This implementation is not copying any values around (which would cost O(n^2)).
Instead it makes a small O(1) calculation every time a value is accessed.

(Please note, that my implementation is not perfect and, for instance, does not work on non-square matrices)

Comment: I still don't get it.. could you write some Main function (for example for a 5x5 matrix), which is rotated clockwise? Just for imagine, how it really works.. Thank you and sorry for my poor knowledge ;)

Comment: I hope it's not too late,  added some more example code and some explanations. Let me know if the approach is useful (and accept the answer maybe :) )

Answer (score 0):

As the matrix has `n^2` entries, the runtime complexity of `O(n^2)` is optimal as it is exactly the length of both the input and the output. That being said, depending on the application, it might not be necessary to rotate the matrix at all, but just manipulate the access to the matrix by rotating the indices on element-wise access.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to complicate things, you can define a `Rotated90Matrix : Matrix` where `Rotated90Matrix[i][j]` returns the correct `Matrix[a][b]`. But that might not be what you want.